# Progress bar circle in Course Overview MOODLE

Tags: moodle, progress

I am wondering how can i increase the size of Progress bar circle in course overview block of moodle. I have tried a lot i.e google and other resources but cant make it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at the template located at `blocks/myoverview/templates/progress-chart.mustache`, and modify the properties of the SVG, as well as adding some CSS to override the default sizes of 70x70 found in several containers.